# Django static files not loading properly

Tags: django

I tried to get my project set up with static files and I do not seem to be successful. I want a global static files instead of an in-app one and so my settings.py is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

And as such my directory is

[image]

The issue I face is that my vendor folders will not load. Only images do and my custom css file.

[image]

What I did is move animate.min.css to the css folder and it worked but I wonder if being inside many folders affects it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**root urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] # It will be deactivated when running collectstatic. Active on localhost
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/') # It will be activated when running collectstatic. Active on server

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: What if I already ran collecstatic? What I see is that js and css files that are within 3 folders are not loading but if I bring them to just one file under static e.g static/css/bootstrap.css it works in contrast to static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: I actually figured it out, apparently the issue is the file name `vendor` not sure why but changing the name to assets fixed the issue. The question now is why?