# App level static files loading in Django but not Project Level

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My app-level static files are loading but not project level

Whenever I try to access static files via localhost/static/css/... I can only access my app-level static files and not project-level. Here is my settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/projects/static'),
]
```

Here is the structure of my file directory structure

```
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|   
+---portfolio
|   |   asgi.py
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|           
+---projects
|   |   admin.py
|   |   apps.py
|   |   models.py
|   |   tests.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |           
|   +---static
|   |   |   
|   |   +---css
|   |   |       projects.css
|   |   |       
|   |   \---img
|   |           test-1.jpg
|   |           test-2.jpg
|   |           test-3.jpg
|           
+---static
|   +---css
|   |       base-template.css
|   |       
|   \---js
+---templates
|       base.html
|       projects.html
|       project_detail.html
```

Comment: Show your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

There is a django static file issue and a related question.

[Django static files not loading properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571281/django-static-files-not-loading-properly/68571626#68571626)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] # It will be deactivated when running collectstatic. Active on localhost
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/') # It will be activated when running collectstatic. Active on server

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```